# Display Caption Under Glyph in TActionToolbar

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-xe7

I have been asked to transition my Delphi application from using a `TRibbon` to a `TActionToolbar`.  I would like the actions in the toolbar to display the caption under the glyph (like in the TRibbon) instead of on the right side, to save space.  However, I cannot find this functionality anywhere in any of the components.  Is there some way I can accomplish this with my `TActionToolbar` and `TActionManager`?

Comment: You could make a different control using `TActionmanager` to hold your actions, that is a bit more powerful than a TActionToolbar. Is that possible for you?  Why not still use the Ribbon, but link to TActionManager actions? Is your requirement to allow customization or to not use Ribbons?

Comment: My task is to "Replace ribbon with Toolbar with large icons".  The problem is that it won't be acceptable to have the icons on the side.  I am open to other controls similar to `TActionToolbar`.

Comment: I suspect you have to make and register your own component class and override its draw code.

Comment: Or just use a standard TToolbar